# One to many relation in pivot table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

I have pivot table and it has one to many relationship with another table, So I am confused with database design and relationship in Laravel Elequent.

[image]

Is this right way to design databse or should I create `id` as primary key for `award_entries` and use it is foreign key in `entry_files`. ?

If I am following existing design (first one), how will I write relation in Laravel eloquent?

Comment: no need to have `user_id` in `entry_files` table again. As it can be referred by `award_id` in `award_entries`, which is a `foreign_key` in `entry_files`.

Comment: The naming convention here is misleading, it should be `users` and `awards` tables and the pivot table would be `award_users` if the intention is to associate a user with awards. Also the "entry_files" `award_entries*` keys should not be in there at all. "award_entries" links awards and users.

Comment: no..this is award entries by user `award_entry`. each entry has multiple files are storing in `entry_files`

Answer (score 0):

Here how your relation will look like. You may need to change model or columns name.

In award_entry model:

```
public function entry_file() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\entry_file','award_entries_award_id');
    }
```

And in Entry_file model:

```
public function award_entries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\award_entries','award_entries_award_id');
    }
```